# Join a MySQL table with itself

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have a MySQL table like attached image.

[image: Translation Table]

[id + locale] is my table key. I have all the terms in English with en_US as my locale, and if I have a translation for any other locale, I add them to the table with same id but different locale. if there is no record for an id in another locale, it means that we still did not translate it.

My excepted result is also in Image. To do that I used this SQL query:

```
    SELECT t1.id as id,
        (SELECT t2.text
        FROM translation t2
        WHERE t2.id = t1.id
        AND t2.locale= :locale
        ) as translated,
        t1.text as english
    FROM translation t1
    WHERE t1.locale = 'en_US'
    AND t1.id= :id
```

(**:id** and **:locale** are my variable parameters)

**My problems:**

1. I still did not benchmark it, but my query looks not efficient to me.
2. I can not search or sort on **translated** column in the query. (or maybe I do not know how to do that)
3. I tried left join (and left outer join), but I seems that it behave differently on MySQL

Do you know any better SQL to do this job? or how can I sort and search on my **translated** column?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Better to use left join. You can search on that by adding a condition to the left side of the query:

```
SELECT t1.id as id,
    t1.text as english,
    t2.text as translated
FROM translation t1
    LEFT JOIN translation t2 on t1.id = t2.id
        and t2.locale = :locale
WHERE t1.locale = 'en_US'
ORDER BY translated
```

This way, you still get the english translation, even if there are no translations meeting your ':locale'.

Answer (score 0):

`Left Join` and `Left Outer Join` are the same.  The `outer` keyword is merely optional.

Try using the following query:

```
SELECT      t1.id as id,
            t1.Text as English,
            t2.Text as Translated
FROM        translation t1
LEFT JOIN   translation t2 ON t2.id = t1.id
WHERE       t1.locale = 'en_US'
AND         t2.locale = :locale
AND         t1.id = :id
```

Comment: This one looks efficient  but I can not get the null value rows for my translated column

Comment: I'm not following - this query would give you exactly that.  What is different between these results and what you're expecting?